# Why does the problem occur even though post.Images [0] exists? TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

post.Images is output from the console.

```
console.log("post.Images " , post.Images);
```

output:

```
[{…}]
0: {id: 5, src: "dokyo11573054801107.png", createdAt: "2019-11-06T15:40:02.000Z", updatedAt: "2019-11-06T15:40:02.000Z", PostId: 14}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

An error occurs in the code below

```
cover={post.Images[0] && <img alt="example" src={`http://localhost:3065:/${post.Images[0]}` } />}
```

error message:
[image: error message]

but it's strange

post.Images [0] exists but undefine error is exists

I can't figure out what's causing it.

Thank you very much for letting me know

Thank you

github:
https://github.com/hyunsokstar/ch6/blob/master/front/components/PostCard.js
https://github.com/hyunsokstar/ch6

Comment: It's possible that  post.Images is getting defined after the render but before the console.log. Can you try cover={post && post.Images && post.Images[0]}

Comment: No error occurs But the image is not output yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the initial render, Images may not be defined by that time, thus you can either create default `[]` in your local component or check if Images exists before accessing its value at position `0`

```
cover={post.Images && post.Images[0] && <img alt="example" src={`http://localhost:3065:/${post.Images[0]}` } />}
```

Alternatively you can destructure from `post` like below and reduce your code as:

```
const { Images = [] } = post;
```

and your code snippet would change like below:

```
cover={Images.length && <img alt="example" src={`http://localhost:3065:/${Images[0]}` } />}
```

Comment: The error is gone but the image is still not printing

Comment: It seems to be almost resolved. Post.Images [0] .src also prints well.
I'll try by tomorrow. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think, when you call `PostCard` and pass `post` into this Component, the `post.Images` data is undefined at the first time of render. So, in `PostCard Component`, the `post.Images` prop will be `undefined`.

I have two ways to resolve this issue:

1. Try pass a default parameter like this:

```
const PostCard = ({ post = {} }) => {
   const { Images = [] } = post; 
   // If post.Images is undefined, default value always is an array

   cover={
      Images[0] && Images[0].src && 
      <img alt="example" src={`http://localhost:3065/${Images[0].src}` } />
   }
}
```

2. Check if `post.Images` and `post.Images[0]` defined, then access to `post.Images[0].src` like this:

```
cover={
   post.Images && post.Images[0] && post.Images[0].src && 
   <img alt="example" src={`http://localhost:3065/${post.Images[0].src}` } />
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer error is disappeared but image is still not showed

Comment: It seems to be almost resolved. Post.Images [0] .src also prints well.
I'll try by tomorrow. Thank you for the answer.